# Cadence Allegro/PCB Editor: Change mechanical pin to electrical pin

Tags: footprint, cadence, allegro

Inside a package/footprint I accidentally deleted the texts of the pin numbers. Thus the electrical pins became mechanical pins. Can I somehow reverse this process and change the mechanical pins back to electrical pins without deleting and placing all pins again? (I am using OrCAD PCB Editor Professional v. 17.2.)

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All you need to do is start the "Add Text" command and select the "Package Geometry/Pin Number" class/subclass. In the command window it will ask you what you want to attach the text to. Pick the pad you are trying to renumber, and then pick the location for the pin number (i.e. click the pad again). Then type the pin number for the pad and click Done (F6). Then just repeat this for each of the pads.

Comment: Perfect, thank you!